# Font style changes when hovering in navigation (only in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The title isn't the best, but I didn't really know how to describe it better.

Problem is, when I hover over my #navigation div it looks like the font-style of my #content div changes. But it only does this on Chrome.
When I view it in Opera or FireFox, it acts normal.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

P.s.: The Ubuntu font is loaded via Google Fonts.

### HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul class="ca-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="ca-icon">F</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Home</h2>
                        <h3 class="ca-sub">Startpagina</h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="ca-icon">H</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Portfolio</h2>
                        <h3 class="ca-sub">Websites en drukwerk</h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="ca-icon">N</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Over Ons</h2>
                        <h3 class="ca-sub">Doel en motto</h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="ca-icon">K</span>
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Contact</h2>
                        <h3 class="ca-sub">Adresgegevens</h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Home - Portfolio - Over Ons - Contact</h1>
        <p>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </a>
            Quisque sed ligula vitae erat sollicitudin gravida. 
            Fusce adipiscing fringilla nibh ut feugiat. 
            In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
            Donec ut nisi in dolor luctus eleifend. 
            Vivamus eleifend suscipit ipsum vitae posuere. 
            Morbi vestibulum erat eu nulla aliquet sagittis quis tempor lorem. 
            Sed orci nunc, dapibus eu cursus sit amet, fringilla a sapien. 
            Nullam non massa nunc.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
background: url('../images/noise.png') rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#content h1, h2, h3 {
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}
#content h1 {
color: rgba(0, 135, 255, 1);
font-size: 32px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 4px;
border-left: 50px solid rgba(0, 135, 255, 1);
line-height: 36px;
}
#content h2 {
color: rgba(77, 184, 255, 1);
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 4px;
border-left: 50px solid rgba(77, 184, 255, 1);
line-height: 28px;
}
#content h3 {
color: rgba(130, 205, 255, 1);
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 4px;
border-left: 50px solid rgba(130, 205, 255, 1);
line-height: 22px;
}
#content p {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
line-height: 20px;
}
#content a {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
transition:         all 300ms ease;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
-moz-transition:    all 300ms ease;
-o-transition:      all 300ms ease;
}
#content a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(130, 205, 255, 1);
color: rgba(130, 205, 255, 1);
}
#wrapper {
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 0;
width: 940px;
height: 100%;
}
#navigation {
position: relative;
width: 220px;
height: 415px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
float: left;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
src: url('websymbols.woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
.ca-menu{
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 220px;
}
.ca-menu li{
width: 220px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
display: block;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
margin-bottom: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child{
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a{
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
}
.ca-icon{
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
font-size: 24px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
line-height: 100px;
position: absolute;
width: 70px;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-content{
position: absolute;
left: 65px;
width: 370px;
height: 60px;
top: 32px;
}
.ca-main{
font-size: 24px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
color: rgba(77, 184, 255, 1);
}
.ca-sub{
font-size: 14px;
color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1);
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}
.ca-menu li:hover{
background: rgba(130, 205, 255, 1);
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
font-size: 36px;
color: rgba(130, 205, 255, 1);
opacity: 0.8;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 1px 1px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
opacity: 1;
color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
-webkit-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(200%);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(200%);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
}
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(200%);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTop {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromTop {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-200%);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
}
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromTop {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-200%);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
}
}
#content {
position: relative;
width: 700px;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
padding: 0;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can You fiddle your Need..? jsfiddle.net

Comment: @VIVEKVIKRANTH Fiddle added.

Comment: Everything is works fine(no changes in Ubuntu font content in both Webkit and moz) except that 'websymbols' it works only on chrome...

Comment: @VIVEKVIKRANTH That's odd.. Because the WebSymbols work just fine for me in Moz..

Here's a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/F0bZl17.png
It's just a couple of milliseconds that it happens, but it's annoying.

Comment: You code in jsfiddle look fine.Cannot reproduce this bug. Maybe problem in your browser? Try reinstall Chrome

Comment: @Anon Could you do me a favour and check your version of Chrome? Maybe it's because I'm on 29 instead of 30.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yuvcpjnhf/ see it.. prob's is n ur browser as Anon said

Comment: I've just reinstalled Chrome, but it's still happening haha.

Comment: You may want to open the site from a different computer? I think this is a local problem

Comment: Yes, yes it was. Works good at home.
Thanks for the help Anon!